# What is the actual definition of momentum?

Tags: momentum

I want to know the actual definition of 'momentum' and why the formula of 'momentum' is $p=m×v$ ; where $m$ and $v$ are respectively the 'mass' and 'velocity' of the body ?

We generally say the definition of 'momentum' as the product of 'mass' and 'velocity' of the body. That is $p=m×v$.

For example- We know that $F=m×a$ , where $F$ is force, $m$ is mass, $a$ is acceleration. Therefore anyone can say the definition of 'force' as the product of 'mass' and 'acceleration' . But the actual definition of 'force' is 'A push or pull on an object resulting in its interaction with another object' .

**So I want the actual definition of 'momentum' and why we say that $p=m×v$ , where $p$ is momentum, $m$ is mass, $v$ is velocity.**

Comment: Ever seen the formula $\vec{p} = m \vec{v}/\sqrt{1-\vec{v}^2/c^2}$ for the momentum of a *relativistic* point particle? Or $\vec{p} \sim \int d^3x \vec{E} \times \vec{B}$ for the momentum of the electromagnetic field? For the *general* definition of the momentum of an arbitrary system see the link in the previous comment.